# Using REGEXP inside mysqli prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to make a simple search process with (noob) codes like this:

```
$prep->prepare("SELECT * FROM details WHERE id REGEXP '?'");
$prep->bind_param("s", $search_query);
```

It gives me this warning:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

I am guessing it could be because the question mark is also used for RegExp (optional previous character).

Any idea about how to use REGEXP inside prepared statements (without conflicting question marks)?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `s` param?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15061783/3234482

Comment: @AliMasudianPour You mean the search query? I "GOT" it (using $_GET). It was fine, it was a problem with the quotes in the prepared query which were not needed. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @AlexL Really? O.o I cannot see how I could have found the answer from the answer link you gave. I guess it needs good eyes, and I wear glasses (or maybe I'm just too noob) :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: The question i linked to was basically asking how to bind parameters in a regexp. You'll notice there are no quotes around `:artist`. My suggestion is taking away the quotes around `?`.

Comment: @AlexL Ah I see. Yes, that was the problem :) Ed Cottrell pointed it out first though. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take out the single quotes around the `?`. Your code should read:

```
$prep->prepare("SELECT * FROM details WHERE id REGEXP ?");
$prep->bind_param("s", $search_query);
```

As it stands now, you are passing in one param, but the `?` in single quotes is treated as a string, not a parameter marker.

Answer (score 3):

What Ed responded is correct.

However, if you happen to need more complex regular expressions, you can use `CONCAT` to create the expression.

```
// Target SQL
//    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` REGEXP "value1|value2|value3";
// Target Prepared Statement SQL
//    SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `field` REGEXP ?|?|?;
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` '
     . 'WHERE `field` REGEXP CONCAT(?, "|", ?, "|", ?)';
$bindings = [$value1, $value2, $value3];

$prepStmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$prepStmt->execute($bindings);
```