# How to use MySQL REGEXP, for searching multiple or single keywords, with both whole and partial word matches, and use prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, prepared-statement

I have been working on this for a few days now and I cannot seem to meet these requirements while properly using prepared statements.

Here are my requirements:

- User must be able to select whole or partial word matches.
- User must be able to enter single or multiple keywords into the search form.
- Keywords must be highlighted in results and reflect whole or partial keywords entered.
- Must make proper use of prepared statements.

I have this all working in Firefox (I have not performed cross browser checks yet) however I don't know how to meet requirement #4.

Here is my code...

```
<?php
$checkbox = "false"; // Checkbox selected in form. Use literal string for value of checkbox.

$keywords = "whole, part";// Search terms entered into form, separated by commas. Use combination of known whole words and partial matches for testing.
$keywords = str_replace(" ","",$keywords);// Close all empty spaces to meet syntax requirements.
$keywords = explode(",",$keywords); // If there are multiple keywords, convert them into an array, otherwise is_array appears to return single words as 'false'.

if($checkbox == "true") // If "whole words only" is checked
    {
    if(is_array($keywords))
        {
        $search = "'[[:<:]]".implode("[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]",$keywords)."[[:>:]]'"; // Whole word REGEXP search for multiple keywords, separated by vertical bar to meet syntax requirements.
        }
    else
        {
        $search = "'[[:<:]]".$keywords."[[:>:]]'"; // Whole word REGEXP search for single keywords.
        }
    }
else
    {
    if(is_array($keywords))
        {
        $search = "'".implode("|",$keywords)."'"; // Any word REGEXP search for multiple keywords, separated by vertical bar to meet syntax requirements.
        }
    else
        {
        $search = "'".$keywords."'"; // Any word REGEXP search for single keywords.
        }
    }
echo $search; // Error checking

$sql = ("SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP $search");
if(!$result_sql = $mysqli->query($sql))
    {
    echo "It broke"; // Change this to something more appropriate.
    }

while($result = $result_sql->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
    $column = $result['column'];
    if($checkbox == "true") // If "whole words only" is checked
        {
        if(is_array($keywords))
            {           
            foreach($keywords as $word)
                {
                $pattern = "/\b".$word."\b/i"; // Adds '\b' before and after the word for whole words only.
                $column = preg_replace($pattern,"<span class=\"highlight\">".$word."</span>", $column); // Applies the highlight CSS to each word found.
                }
            }
        else
            {
            $pattern = "/\b".$word."\b/i"; // // Adds '\b' before and after the word for whole words only.
            $column = preg_replace($pattern,"<span class=\"highlight\">".$word."</span>", $column); // Applies the highlight CSS to each word found.
            }
        }
    else
        {
        if(is_array($keywords))
            {           
            foreach($keywords as $word)
                {
                $pattern = "/".$word."/i";
                $column = preg_replace($pattern,"<span class=\"highlight\">".$word."</span>", $column); // Applies the highlight CSS to each word found.
                }
            }
        else
            {
            $pattern = "/".$word."/i";
            $column = preg_replace($pattern,"<span class=\"highlight\">".$word."</span>", $column); // Applies the highlight CSS to each word found. 
            }
        }
    echo "column: ".$column;
    }
?>
```

**EDIT  :**

Found one problem. If I search for the word "light" as a partial match, it picks up on `class="highlight"`. I suppose the only answer to that is to use some gibberish for a `class` name?

Comment: If your problem is #4, look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890498/using-regexp-inside-mysqli-prepared-statement-in-php

Comment: @rjdown Thanks, I did see that post, however it didn't work for me. I was using `$stmt->bind_param('s', $search);` and when echoed I got `'whole|part'` so I don't see why it wouldn't. I replaced the question mark so it read `REGEXP 'whole|part'` and it worked fine.