# Searching in mySQL table using REGEXP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo, prepared-statement

So basically you can use REGEXP to search for anything that contains one or more strings of your wish. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbTable WHERE LOWER(description) REGEXP 'foo|bar'
```

But I'm having trouble using this dynamically with user input using prepared PDO statements:

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <form id="search" action="/search.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="searchQ" value="<?php echo $searchQ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  $hCon = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost_n;dbname=$dbname_n",$dbuser_n,$dbpasswd_n,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
  if (isset($_POST['searchQ']) && $_POST['searchQ'] != '') {
      $searchQ = htmlspecialchars($_POST['searchQ']);
      $searchQ = strtolower($searchQ); 
      $searchQ = str_replace(" ","|",$searchQ); //replace spaces with | because it means OR in regex

      $q = $hCon->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $dbtable . " WHERE LOWER(description) REGEXP ':searchQ'");
      $q->execute(array(':searchQ'=>$searchQ));

      while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          echo "<p>" . $row['description'] . "</p>";
      }
  }
?>
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to take off the quotes around the binded parameter (presuming `$searchQ` outputs as the regex you've described). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061593/regexp-with-pdo-mysql

Comment: If you are using a case-insensitive collation, you don't need `LOWER()`.